# git add my remote for pushing submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a main app that stored in *our* git. Within that app we are using a third-party component that's hosted on *github*. We make numerous customizations to this component, and as such felt that to make updates easier, we should add the component as a submodule.

It was my understanding that by adding this component as a submodule, we would be able to pull upstream changes from *github* and merge those into our submodule. We would then push those changes to *our* git.

I successfully added the component as a submodule, and cloned it into my app's directory. I've merged in all our modifications, and committed those locally.

My question is, how do I now add our git as a remote for the submodule so that I can push all my customizations to that server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your submodule is just another git repo. The same steps for adding an additional remote and pushing the changes apply here as well.

```
cd <DIRECTORY_OF_YOUR_SUBMODULE>
git remote add <REMOTE-NAME> <PRIVATE_GIT_REPO_URL>
git fetch <REMOTE-NAME>

# Now you should be able to merge, rebase or cherrypick or any other
# merge strategy you prefer.

# After merging push the changes into your remote
git push <REMOTE-NAME> <LIST_OF_REFS>
```

Comment: I assumed as much, but was scared of messing up my repository. Cheers!